# JHipster error when i first try to run

Tags: jhipster

```
  cs@cs-270E5J:~/JHipster$ yo jhipster

    /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/app/index.js:15
    const constants = require('../generator-constants');
    ^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
        at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object._storeAsPath.Object.defineProperty.get [as jhipster:app] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:40:23)
        at Store.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:64:35)
        at Environment.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:260:16)
        at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:292:24)
    cs@cs-270E5J:~/JHipster$
```

i installed jhipster without errors. only those:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/usr/lib
└── generator-jhipster@3.1.0
```

when i go into jhipster folder and try to run jhipster with yo jhipster, it gives error in the s tart. Why? I have all update

i tried to update yeoman and errors:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-35-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/access-error.js:4:18)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/writable.js:30:25
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:232:16
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/caneraydin/npm-debug.log
```

> Yeoman Doctor
>   Running sanity checks on your system
>
> ✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
>   ✔ Global configuration file is valid
>   ✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
>   ✖ Node.js version

I also get errors. when i run sudo npm install -g npm
but i have latest version of nodejs?

look:

> caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:~$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   nodejs is already the newest version.
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     authbind libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java
>     libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java libntdb1 libtomcat7-java
>     linux-headers-3.13.0-83 linux-headers-3.13.0-83-generic python-ntdb
>     tomcat7-common
>   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
>   caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:~$

Comment: What version of node do you have installed and what Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04. node -v v0.10.25 nodejs i am following here http://jhipster.github.io/installation/ 
after this command npm install -g generator-jhipster, i did this
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:/home$ sudo mkdir jhipster
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:/home$ ls
caneraydin  jhipster  lost+found
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:/home$ mkdir app
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘app’: Permission denied
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:/home$ sudo mkdir app
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:/home$ cd app/
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:/home/app$ yo jhipster

Answer (score 2):

The doc recommends to use node LTS version, so 0.10.x is probably too old and does not support const keyword. I think the oldest version that could work is probably 0.12.x in case you can't upgrade to latest LTS.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ yes from here i saw it but i downloaded latest from there. i open bin folder and when i execute or execute in terminal, it deosnot do anything. also from command line i cant install. It only says newest version is installed. What to do?

Comment: Also on Ubuntu, it's better not to install node using sudo, just use nvm and install the versions you want

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install curl
For Node.js v4

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Alternatively, for Node.js v5:

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Comment: It's always better not to install node using sudo, just use nvm and install the versions you want and swirtch between them as you need it.